# Vue-Firebase: Collect all the keys from firebase entries in script

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

Trying to understand how Firebase handles its entries, i been trying to collect all the keys from a child.

```
  <div v-for = "item in TeamArray">
        {{item['.key']}}
  </div>
```

This works when i try to collect the keys from the HTML section which is fine.
But i want to save all the keys in an array.
But when i try to save the keys inside an array and not just print them Vue gets into a infinity loop and will fill the array with the same values over and over.

```
 <div v-for = "item in TeamArray">
        {{Save_Keys(item['.key'])}}
   </div>
```

If TeamArray can be iterated in HTML i thought it could be used the same way with a foreach loop.

```
Get_Keys: function () {
        this.$firebaseRefs.TeamArray.forEach(function(key){
          team_key_list.push(key['.key']);
        });
        for(let i = 0; i < team_key_list.length; i++)
          console.log(team_key_list[i])
      }
```

But i get an error that forEach isnt a function for TeamArray.

How does Firebase works in this manner? Does Vue let me iterate over it in the HTML but in the JS something else is needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a VueFire expert, but can help explain some of the Firebase bits. Your `this.$firebaseRefs.TeamArray` is a [Firebase database reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference): a reference to a location in the database. It does not actually have any of the data yet, which is why your loop over the reference fails.

To get the data from a database reference, you attach a listener. The simplest way to do this is with `once()`, which reads the data once:

```
this.$firebaseRefs.TeamArray.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child){
    team_key_list.push(child.key);
  });
  console.log(team_key_list);
});
```

There may be some mistakes in this code, but mostly it is just basic Firebase JavaScript SDK ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)) and then glancing at the relevant [VueFire code](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/blob/master/src/vuefire.js#L143) and [Vue.js code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/7a145d86430bad65271f4d6ab1344b215fefe52a/src/core/observer/index.js#L134).